# ¿Cómo optimizar el código En Laravel y blade?

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-8

El problema que planteo es el siguiente tengo que hacer un crud de 10 tablas que tienen los mismos campos y que solo cambia la información dentro de esos campos, como puedo optimizar el código para no tener que hacer 10 modelos,10 controladores y 10 vistas Blade.

En cuanto a los campos de las tablas son dos campos, un campo nombre y un campo valor.
nombre(String),valor(int).

Por favor abstenerse la gente que va a responder el típico "Pues parametrizando", si iluminado de la vida hasta ese punto llego yo, lo que quiero saber es como lo hago para evitar tener que perder el tiempo copiando, pegando y modificado y poder hacerlo con un controlador y un entorno de vistas blade. Se que los modelos seguramente los tenga que hacer pero hay alguna forma de saltarme el tener que crear 10 controladores o 10 crud de blade.

Un saludo.

Comment: Estaría bien que ya que vienes a preguntar aquí, seas agradecido y no preguntes con ese tono de superioridad. Ya que si has venido a preguntar es por algo

Comment: Hola ???, donde ves tu tono de superioridad ?, si lo  único que no quiero son listillos que me den respuestas que ya sé, lo que quiero es gente que aporte por que esta pregunta es una pregunta generalizada y yo agradezco cada buena respuestas no me sirve de nada que me digas parametriza o cualquier chorrada parecida.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes tres tablas con los mismos campos y los mismos nombres de campos si que podrás crear un único modelo con los campos de las tablas comunes y 1 controlador para redirigir a la vista (blade).

Yo probaría a crear un único modelo con el nombre de la tabla que usará por defecto y un controlador con un método `getSharedModelView` pasándole el tipo de datos y en base a esto cambiar el nombre de la tabla y recoger los datos y pasarlos a la vista.

De esta forma creo que funcionaría aunque no lo he probado pero yo lo enfocaría de una forma similar a esta.

`Model`:

```js
class SharedModel extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
    
        protected $table = 'table_name'; // default table
    
        protected $fillable = [...];

        public function setTable (string $newTable) {
             $this->table = $newTable;
        }
        
        public function getDefaultTable () {
             return $this->table;
        }
    }
```

`Controller`:

```js
public function getSharedModelView ($type) {

    $sharedModel = new SharedModel();

    $dbName = $sharedModel->getDefaultTable();

    if ($type === '...') $dbName = '...';

    $sharedModel->setTable($dbName);

    return view('view_name')->with([
        'type' => $type,
        'data' => SharedModel::all(),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pensando más a fondo...

Si las tablas van a mantenerse con los mismos campos a lo largo del tiempo y no van a crecer, lo que ocasione tener que reescribir el código y dado que comparten campos, diría que podrías añadir un campo más `type` en una única tabla en lugar de en 3. En este campo se almacena el tipo que hace que sean tablas diferentes y de esta manera con un único modelo podrás:

```
$typeModel = Model::where('type','=',':tipo');
```

De esta manera podrás obtener todos los item de la tabla de un tipo concreto en lugar de tener que controlar si es un modelo u otro.